# Centrally place menu items in bottom navigation view without text

Tags: android, xml, menu, material-design, bottomnavigationview

I am using a bottom Navigation View with menus. I need to place the menu icons in the center of the BNV as I don't want to place text with the icons.

Here is my bottom Navigation View:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_dashboard"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/dashboard_navigation" />


        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:elevation="12dp"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</layout>
```

And here is the menu code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<item
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:title=""
    android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/chatFragment"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/chat_icon"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nonSulinCommunityFragment"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/nonsulin_community_icon"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/notificationsFragment"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/notification_icon"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/profile_icon"

        />

</menu>
```

Here is the ss of the bottom nav and I need to place icons in the center of the bottom Nav Menu.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `android:title=""` in the xml file and it should work

Comment: can u share the updated code with the new tag added ?

Comment: where I am suppose to add gravity in bottom nav view or constraint layout?

Comment: constraint layout

Comment: get rid of the `android:title`, that may help i think

Comment: I tried, but it didn't allow. By the way, I have resolved the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved the issue by changing

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

to

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
```

as I was not using any title with the menu.

Comment: oh yeah i missed that ! gg !